# If char was only to be used with an if statement, how can it be used with an %c or %s?

Tags: c, char

The problem I'm getting at is with this following code.

Basically, I'm confused since I know that `char` should be matched with `%c`.

Yet, I also know that `%c` gets only one character, which means that in order to get the word in the if statement ('man' or 'woman'), it has to become a `%s`.

But then, `%s` doesn't match with `char`.

I would like to ask:
if I were to leave char as it is, 
what would be the problem with my idea and code that is making the result unable to come out properly?

```
int main() {
    char gender;

    printf("Enter gender(M/F) : ");
    scanf("%c", &gender);
    if (scanf("%c", &gender) == 'M') {
        printf("Man");
    }
    else if (scanf("%c", &gender) == 'F') {
        printf("Woman");
    }

    printf("The gender is %c.", gender);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why are you doing `scanf` 3 times. Why not just use the `gender` variable which already contains the inputted char after the first `scanf`?

Comment: `scanf` returns the number of successful matches.  You want to compare `gender == 'M'`, not the value returned from scanf.

Comment: But why are you using `scanf` at all?  It's a can of worms.  If you are new to C, just pass the value as a command line parameter or read it with fgetc.

Comment: I'm actually a beginner and tried to input M or F to output a Man or Women within a statement..

I actually tried putting in ```gender``` instead of ```scanf``` but the outcome would keep coming out as ```WomanThe gender is F.``` or ```ManThe gender is M```

If it's not too much of a bother, could you please help me out with this part..

Comment: `printf("Man")` --> `printf("Man\n")`, `printf("Woman")` --> `printf("Woman\n")`, and `printf("The gender is %c.", gender)` --> `printf("The gender is %c.\n", gender)`

Comment: Note that `scanf` _consumes_ the input. So after `scanf("%c", &gender);` you cannot do it again (without asking the user for more input...).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you use the getchar()  instead?

```
int main()
        {

            printf("Enter gender(M/F) : ");
            char gender = getchar();

            if (gender == 'M')
                printf("Man\n")

            if (gender == 'W')
                printf("Woman\n")

            printf("The gender is %c.\n", gender);

            return 0;
        }
```

Also its a good practice to enclosure your reading into a while loop and break from it only  if the char that you got from the user is acceptable (Check for EOF or any other char , show an error message and try again.)

Alternative just use scan only one time:

```
  int main()
        {

            printf("Enter gender(M/F) : ");
            char gender;
            scanf(" %c", &gender);

            if (gender == 'M')
                printf("Man\n")

            if (gender == 'W')
                printf("Woman\n")

            printf("The gender is %c.\n", gender);

            return 0;
        }
```

Comment: I actually tried putting in gender instead of scanf like you have shown me on the second code,
but the outcome would keep coming out as ```WomanThe gender is F.``` or ```ManThe gender is M``` 

What could be the problem in this part? could you teach me please

Comment: What do you want to show after. The gender is Woman? What value do you want the gender variable to have?

Comment: @Learner_15 You don't have a newline in your `printf`. Ex:`printf("Man\n");` When not using any formatting, consider using `puts()`.

Comment: The result I wanted was actually ```The gender is Woman``` or ```The gender is Man``` hmm.. then am I actually missing lines in the code such as not using ```puts()```? So the problem is not actually in the logic or order, but in not using certain commands?

Comment: OH! apart from that, I think I found out the problem. It was actually the ```" %c"```... I was typing it in as ```"%c"```.. sorry everyone.. and thank you very much for the feedback. I think I can kind of handle it from now